# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies

Tags: .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that calls an external dll. The stored procedure code as below :

WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
EXTERNAL NAME "Some External dll"

I do not have the source code of this extermal dll, but when I execute the stored procedure I get the above error. I have .net framework 3.5 and 4.8 installed, and I could see that the referenced dll is there on server, but it seems it can't be accessed?

All permissions are granted, what else I need to check?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server CLR never loads assemblies from outside the database.  You must run [CREATE ASSEMBLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-assembly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to install every dependent assembly into the database.

Howver, you shouldn't do this with .NET Framework Assemblies (like System.Drawing).  Any time the .NET Framework is updated on the server you have to re-load all the .NET Framework assemblies.  Plus some .NET Framework assemblies are "mixed-mode" and SQL Server will not let you install them in a database, plus .NET Framework assemblies other than the few on the "blessed list" are not tested or supported for running in SQL CLR.

```
The libraries/namespaces supported by CLR integration in SQL Server are:

CustomMarshalers
Microsoft.VisualBasic
Microsoft.VisualC
mscorlib
System
System.Configuration
System.Core
System.Data
System.Data.OracleClient
System.Data.SqlXml
System.Deployment
System.Security
System.Transactions
System.Web.Services
System.Xml
System.Xml.Linq
```

[Supported .NET Framework Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/database-objects/supported-net-framework-libraries?view=sql-server-ver15#supported-libraries)

Whatever you're doing, you should be doing in a *seperate process* outside SQL Server.  This can be a PowerShell script, run by SQL Agent, a standalone console application, etc.

Comment: How to re-load all .net framework assembles? The stored prcoedures I'm using is installed by a 3rd party application, it is part of the application, and this dll I see it registered in "Assemblies" in sql server database, but it sounds it make a reference internally for System.Drawing, and it can't find it! This stored procedure should be working, do you have any suggestion, please?

Comment: The third party should have a procedure for you to do that.

Answer (score -1):

Ok the issue was solved, it was due to a windows update affecting .NET framework 4.8, I uninstalled the update , and it's working now!